# Squarespace Events by Month

Tags: squarespace, jsontemplate

I’m attempting to create a custom list of events for my Squarespace website. I would like to show the events separated by the month in which they are happening. For example, I will have a header that says “June” and then list all of the events that are happening in June below it. I would love to do this in the template code rather than by using an archive block so that I can customize the list to show the exact elements that I need. The code below shows my attempt to display the items that I want from events that happen in June however, the other image is my result. My .equal? predicate isn’t working in the way that I intended. If anyone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

```
<div class="events_month_loop">
 {.repeated section items}
   {.equal?:{startDate|date %B:"June"}
     <div id="events-{id}">
       <div class="event_info">
         <a href="{fullUrl}">Event Link</a>
       </div>
      </div>
    {.end}
  {.or}
    <p>No events in June</p>
  {.end}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`var` directive](https://developers.squarespace.com/json-t-directives#VarDirective) to accomplish this.

```
<squarespace:query collection="events">
  <div class="events_month_loop">
   {.repeated section items}
     {.var @smonth startDate|date %B}
     {.equal? @smonth "June"}
       <div id="events-{id}">
         <div class="event_info">
           <a href="{fullUrl}">Event Link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      {.end}
    {.or}
      <p>No events in June</p>
    {.end}
  </div>
</squarespace:query>
```

One note: I'm assuming this is in a `squarespace:query`. If this is in a `.list` file, then some changes would be required.

Also, the above works in the case where you are hard-coding the month, as in your example code.

If you wanted to dynamically compare to the current month, I think the closest you could get would be to compare it to the last date the website content was modified. In many cases, that would be sufficient:

```
<squarespace:query collection="events">
  <div class="events_month_loop">
   {.var @cmonth website.contentModifiedOn|date %B}
   {.repeated section items}
     {.var @smonth startDate|date %B}
     {.equal? @smonth @cmonth}
       <div id="events-{id}">
         <div class="event_info">
           <a href="{fullUrl}">Event Link</a>
         </div>
        </div>
      {.end}
    {.or}
      <p>No events in {@cmonth}</p>
    {.end}
  </div>
</squarespace:query>
```

Comment: You're correct, I did use this in a squarespace:query. This worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

A tip that Brandon gave me a long time ago was to use limit="0" on the squarespace:query to just get the upcoming events, otherwise the query will get the past events too! Very handy.

```
<squarespace:query collection="events" limit="0">
```